# How to set word break in span in css

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I am using the radio buttons but the label beside the radio button is too long for the fixed screen. So some part of text is not showing. I tried `word-break:break-word` but it doesnt work.
Currently the code is

```
<label class="ant-radio-wrapper"><span class="ant-radio"><input type="radio" class="ant-radio-input" value="1"><span class="ant-radio-inner"></span></span><span>Comté Réserve PDO 36-42 Months Old 200g</span></label>
```

and it looks like [image]

How to fix this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This one is easy. You can put a tag break `<br>` inside tag span to break the line.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options in my opinion but there are a lot.

First One:

you can use flexbox if you know it's good otherwise you just need to put these below CSS in your ant-radio-wrapper class name.

```
.ant-radio-wrapper {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Second One:

You can resize your font size by default font size is 16px

```
.ant-radio-wrapper {
  font-size: 12px
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The long answer is, there's something wrong with your layout. Normally a line of text in a span will break to a new line.

```css
.container{
  width:200px;
  border:solid 2px #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <label class="ant-radio-wrapper">
    <span class="ant-radio">
      <input type="radio" class="ant-radio-input" value="1"/>
      <span class="ant-radio-inner"></span>
    </span>
    <span>Comté Réserve PDO 36-42 Months Old 200g</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use flexbox

```css
label {
  display: flex;
  /* for demo */
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<label class="ant-radio-wrapper"><span class="ant-radio"><input type="radio" class="ant-radio-input" value="1"><span class="ant-radio-inner"></span></span><span>Comté Réserve PDO 36-42 Months Old 200g</span></label>
```